# how to return string from constructor function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, return-value

as you know when we new a Date object it returns an string,

it means when you execute this code

```
console.log(new Date());
```

it returns an string like this: `Sun Jan 17 2016 16:26:55 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)`

i want to do exact the same thing and return an string when somebody new my object...

is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by 'somebody new my object'?

Comment: So you have a constructor, and want to convert the instances to strings?

Comment: @TarunDugar excuse me for my bad English ,,, I mean if my object is Date2 then I want to return an string when someone call `new Date2()`

Comment: you cannot do new Date2(). If you want to convert something to string use toString()

Comment: `new Date()` does *not* return a string. It's just the console that formats `Date` objects as such.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You can to use `Object.prototype.toString` (reference in [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)):

```
function MyObject () {
  this.numProperty = 1;
  this.strProperty = "some string";
}
MyObject.prototype.toString = function (){
 return this.strProperty;
}

// example usage:
var obj = new MyObject();
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = obj;
```

EDIT:
for `console.log` behavior you can use either

```
console.log(obj.toString());
```

or

```
Console.prototype.logO = function (obj) {
    this.log(obj.toString());
}
// and then
console.logO(obj);
```

The last line is what you wanted in the first place, but I would go for the first option as it's less wordy.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyme6vLa/).

Comment: thanks for answer
but as you can see in your fiddle, it works with `innnerHTML()` function but it's not working with `console.log()`.
is there any way to makes it work in console.log?