# Log a string when console.log(new X()) is executed

Tags: javascript, string, constructor, type-conversion, console.log

In interview, I was asked that any string for e.g. "Hello" should be consoled when below line of code is executed.

```
console.log(new X())
```

This should be achieved without any additional console.log statements.

I tried something like:

```
function X() {   return "Hello"; }
```

But it is not returning a string. It is returning the newly created instance of X.

Was this a trick question?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34838587/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't understand why that is a duplicate. Nothing in that answer explains how to get `console.log(new X)` to log a string?

Comment: I think [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) is the keyword here.

Comment: In Node.js _specifically_: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54667225/3001761. But a constructor can't return a primitive value (or rather, that value is ignored: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3350215/30017610).

Comment: Right, the original question does not answer the question I have posted. If it was indeed a trick question and not achievable in browsers, then please post it as answer. Voted to reopen

Comment: I think `X` needs to be a class with constructor that returns "Hello," per the `new` documentation I linked above.

Comment: @mykaf I tried that already and added that in my answer too.

Comment: @Murtuza, I don't see any answers and the constructor is not in your question.

Comment: Not mentioned in the dupe, but mentioned in the other question that @jonrsharpe linked (What is returned from a constructor) using the knowledge that if a constructor returns an object, `new` will return that object rather than a new instance, the question now becomes: "What object logs a string when sent to console.log?" One answer is a text node. `function X() { return document.createTextNode("Hello") }; console.log(new X()); //"hello"`

Comment: @chiliNUT Brilliant. Your solution works. I must add that its not very obvious to reach your solution by referencing other question, at least to me it was not. 

So it will help others if you can post this as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @mykaf Sorry, I meant I added in my question.

Comment: Glad it worked! I can't post as an answer because this question is still closed.

Comment: @chiliNUT the question is reopened. You can add your answer.

Comment: @Murtuza, there is still no class or constructor in your question.

Comment: @mykaf a function is treated as a constructor when you use `new`

Comment: The first question would be "for which target"? Was this for Deno, Bun, Node, or browsers? And if the last one, a _specific_ browser, or all of them? And of course, are we running in strict mode, or "sloppy" mode? This feels like one of those "we don't actually care about the answer itself, we want to hear you ask a boatload of questions before you even start solving this" =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I would say this was for browsers since the interview was for frontend engineer. "we don't actually care about the answer itself, we want to hear you ask a boatload of questions before you even start solving this" totally agree. May be interviewer wanted to know my knowledge as to what a constructor returns. Since I mentioned `function X() {   return "Hello"; }`, which is obviously incorrect since constructor does not return primitive types, the interviewer got what he was looking for :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl; dr;

```js
function X() {
   return document.createTextNode("Hello");
}
console.log(new X()); //"Hello"
```

Explanation:

An immediate thought is to somehow use `toString`, but it doesn't work. Logging a plain object or class that implements `toString` will still output the object structure when you log it, so that won't work.

2 parts of the spec are key to solve this:

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

> When a function is called with the new keyword, the function will be used as a constructor. new will do the following things:
>
> ...
>
> 4. If the constructor function returns a non-primitive, this return value becomes the result of the whole new expression. Otherwise, if the constructor function doesn't return anything or returns a primitive, `newInstance` is returned instead.

You have little control of how a user defined class will be logged. But maybe there is a built in object that will log text, so we need to figure out what *that* might be, and then return it in the constructor. What built in objects log text?

(https://console.spec.whatwg.org/)

> § 1.1.6. log(...data)
>
> Perform Logger("log", data).

> § 2.1. Logger(logLevel, args)
>
> The logger operation accepts a log level and a list of other arguments. Its main output is the **implementation-defined side effect of printing the result to the console**.

> § 2.3. Printer(logLevel, args[, options])
>
> The printer operation is implementation-defined. It accepts a log level indicating severity, a List of arguments to print...Elements appearing in args will be one of the following:
>
> - JavaScript objects of any type.
> - Implementation-specific representations of printable things such as a stack trace or group.
> - Objects with either generic JavaScript object formatting or **optimally useful formatting** applied.

> § 2.3.3. Common object formats
>
> Typically objects will be printed in a format that is suitable for their context.... An object with generic JavaScript object formatting is a potentially expandable representation of a generic JavaScript object. **An object with optimally useful formatting is an implementation-specific, potentially-interactive representation of an object judged to be maximally useful and informative.**

^^ Paydirt. We need to find an object that has an "optimally useful formatting" which is not the object tree. I couldn't find an exhaustive list, but lets think about it. I know offhand that logging a dom node logs the html tree instead of the object tree:

[image: console.log(document.body);]

So I took a leap and guessed that logging a text node might just log the text, and it worked:

[image: console.log text node]

and there it is

```js
function X() {
   return document.createTextNode("Hello");
}
console.log(new X()); //"Hello"

class X {
    constructor() {
        return document.createTextNode("Hello");
    }
}
console.log(new X()); // "Hello"
```

see also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68449803/2079345
- [What is returned from a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350215/what-is-returned-from-a-constructor)

Comment: Clever, but I'm not sure I would pull that off in an interview. Or only with a large disclaimer :-)

Comment: And note that this will still log the object structure in the Firefox dev console, which will give you the same expandable object it gives for any other object, with `#text "Hello"` as summary caption, rather than just the text "Hello" (in which case we might as well just return a `new String("hello")` =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's fair, and the spec says its implementation-dependent so I wouldn't expect it to work cross-browser, but for this interview question  `#text "Hello"` might have still counted :-)  `new String("hello")` won't work though, chrome and ff both log the object structure for me

Comment: Oh, no, absolutely, I just meant if we're getting stuff printed in addition anyway, might as well go with the simplest thing. I honestly expect this question to be about "do you know how to ask questions about tasks, yourself, instead of trying to immediately walk off without all the details", not about how to ninja-log to the console =D

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans oh i see what you mean. I think you're right. If I was tasked with this at work, I would immediately have lots of questions

Answer (score 1):

This is "technically" impossible to do, as `console.log` is implementation-defined, and even something clever that works in -say- Chrome won't work in Firefox, or any other browser you haven't tested it in yet, or haven't even heard of yet.

But we're not just given `X`, we're also given `console.log` itself. And `console.log` is implementation-defined. And we were just asked to implement something.

So let's be spec-compliant and just *define a new implementation for the `console.log` function*.

If someone *really* needs to do this (which they don't), the way to actually make this happen is by exploiting the fact that we're in JavaScript and we can just change how `console.log` works so that in the specific case given, and *only* the specific case given, it does what was asked. Let's make this red pen write blue:

```js
const originalLog = console.log.bind(console);

console.log = function log(...args) {
  if (args.length === 1) {
    if (args[0].__proto__.constructor.name === `X`) {
      // Just replace the value. How you do that replacement
      // is of course entirely up to you, the "dumbest" way
      // is to just hardcode a string, but you have plenty
      // of options here based on X itself, or the JS engine,
      // or the user agent, or the time of day, etc. etc.
      args[0] = "hello";
    }    
  }
  originalLog(...args);
};

class X {}

console.log(new X());
```

Is it in the spirit of the question? We have no idea, there are nowhere near enough details in the question for us to actually start implementing anything (which was probably the point of the question: to see if someone would try to sus out an exhaustive list of acceptance criteria before getting to work).

But does it work in any JS engine you run this in? You bet.

And more importantly, would you ever *actually* need this? To which the answer, perhaps surprisingly, is "yes, absolutely. You're probably using code that does this on the daily already, just with a much better use-case: your test framework".

For testing and debugging it's pretty common to "wrap" functions in redeclarations, and have [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) wrappers for objects, so that we can insert our own code into existing code paths for testing and debugging in a way that won't affect the code in production.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps ...

- use an immediately invoked (arrow) function expression
  for wrapping a behavior around the original `console.log`
  which does stringify the first of the passed parameters.
- implement a class with a prototypal `toString` method.

  (for a plain constructor function implement its own `toString`.)

```js
// - use an immediately invoked (arrow) function expression
//   for wrapping a behavior around the original `console.log`
//   which does stringify the first of the passed parameters.
console.log = (log => {
  return function logger (value, ...args) {

    log(String(value), ...args);      
  };
})(console.log.bind(console));

// - implement a class with a prototypal `toString` method.
class X {
  toString() {
    return 'Hello.';
  }
}
// - for a plain constructor function implement its own `toString`.
function Y() {
  this.toString = () => 'Goodbye.';
}

console.log(new X);
console.log(new Y);

console.log(new Y, new X);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: not relevant here (at least, given how zero information the question gave ;) but using an arrow function means we can't rely on `this` to refer to "the owner" at runtime, since by definition it'll be whatever it was at declare-time. So that arrow function should in general be a regular function.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ... the arrow function as IIFE is totally ok, since the binding of the console context to its original `log` method happens at the IIFE's call time as a passed parameter. Within the IIFE's function body a `this` context therefore is not needed (The owner at the inner `logs` execution/run time always is `console`). Thus it doesn't matter whether one chooses an arrow function expression or a function expression.

Comment: Ah, nm, missed the fact that your arrow function itself returned a plain function. A bit more work than directly rebinding a plain function, but the same effect without polluting the scope with the original function, which is always nice.